# List of unique strings in database table using Linq?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have a "Tickets" table with somewhat following structure (removed unnecessary columns)

```
int | string   | int   |
ID  | Window   | Count |
------------------------
0   | Internet | 10    |
1   | Phone    | 20    |
2   | Fax      | 15    |
3   | Fax      | 10    |
4   | Internet | 5     |
.   | .        | .     |
.   | .        | .     |
```

And I have mapped this table to a class "Ticket". So I can get all records like this:

```
var tickets = from t in db.Tickets
              select t;
```

Now I need to get the list of unique window names in the table. For above table, list would look something like:

- Internet
- Phone
- Fax

Is there anyway to create this list without fetching all records and iterating over them?

I am using SQL Server 2008 express edition.

EDIT:
Thanks for the answers guys it solved the above problem. Just being greedy but is there any way to *also* get the total of count for each window. For example:

- Internet = 15
- Phone = 25
- Fax = 20

Comment: Without more database side magic (a lookup table, triggers, etc) - the database will need to fetch the whole list in order to apply the distinct across them.  The answers below are correct, just notice that the database will still scan the whole table/index.

Comment: The database will, but the .NET code won't fetch all the records and iterate over them locally, which is what I suspect Hemant was worried about.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about:

```
var tickets = db.Tickets.Select(t => t.Window).Distinct();
```

I prefer to only use query expressions when I'm doing more than one operation, but if you like them the equivalent is:

```
var tickets = (from t in db.Tickets
               select t.Window).Distinct();
```

To get the counts, you need to group:

```
var tickets = from t in db.Tickets
              group t by t.Window into grouped
              select new { Window=grouped.Key, 
                           Total=grouped.Sum(x => x.Count) };

foreach (var entry in tickets)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", entry.Window, entry.Total);
}
```

Note that this should all end up being performed at the database side - examine the SQL query to check this.

Comment: I think the second sample should be t.Window? I am really a beginner so not really sure...

Answer (score 3):

```
 var query2 = from ticket in db.tickets 

 group window by ticket.Window into result
 select new
 {
     Name = result.Window,
     Sum = result.Sum(i => i.Count)
 };
```

Comment: I think you mean "group ticket" instead of "group window". Also, the "result" range variable then won't have a Window property, but it will have a Key property.

Answer (score 1):

[Linq Samples Part 11](http://srtsolutions.com/blogs/billwagner/archive/2006/04/10/linq-samples-part-11.aspx) by Bill Wagner should help you. Just call the `Distinct()` function on your Linq result. It's as simple as that.

```
var tickets = (from t in db.Tickets
               select t).Distinct();
```

**[EDIT]**

Concering the numbers of the occurences, [see this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336754.aspx#simple1) as a hint.

```
        int[] numbers = { 5, 4, 1, 3, 9, 8, 6, 7, 2, 5 };

        var numberGroups =
            from n in numbers
            group n by 5 into g
            select g;

        g.Count(); // occurences
```

Comment: I am confused, how does this code know which field we are seeking distinct in?

Comment: It returns the list of *unique* rows, such that that the combination of ALL fields is distinct. This translates to the SELECT DISTINCT database mechanism.

Comment: It's comparing the resulting objects. You can provide a custom comparer by implementing the IEqualityComparer interface and pass the comparer as parameter to Distinct().

Comment: Updated with the answer to the follow-up question.

Comment: The follow up question was NOT about the number of occurrences. It was about calculating the sum of "Count" over the rows for a distinct value of "Window".

Comment: Oh, sorry, I completely misunderstood you there!

Answer (score 1):

The query will be evaluated inside the store.

```
var windows = db.Tickets.Select(ticket => ticket.Window).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .Distinct() operator - it'll make a SELECT DISTINCT to the database, giving exactly what you ask for.